# Excel VBA range copy from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a line of code that I am having issues troubleshooting.

```
Sheets("data").Range(cells(2,1), cells(2, column).Copy
```

I'm getting a `1004 application or object defined error` on this. The code works if I remove the worksheet selection or replace the range chunk with a hardcoded reference (e4:e50 for example), but won't work together.

Comment: Try adding `Sheets ("data")` before each `cells`. Edit: also make sure `column` > 0. Edit2 thanks to Scott: because the computer needs to know _which_ `cells` you mean. Edit3: in before Scott, Mat or anyone tells me to post answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner Why not =P

Comment: Oh for... Thanks that fixed it! I can't seem to ever get with blocks working, but the manual typing option works just fine thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have the Range looking at one sheet and the Cells are looking at the active sheet.  You need to make sure they are looking at the same sheet.

You can do this in line:

```
Sheets ("data").Range(Sheets ("data").cells (2,1), Sheets ("data").cells (2, column)). Copy
```

Or you can use a With Block for less typing

```
With Sheets ("data")
    .Range(Sheets (.cells (2,1), .cells (2, column)). Copy
End With
```

Comment: Why is it hotter in the summer?

Comment: The answer many college graduates give is that the earth is closer to the sun during the summer. @findwindow

Comment: Oh duh. You're interviewing engineers. I would have been like it's more romantic to feed each other ice cream than hot cocoa.

Comment: @findwindow My father quotes a study of recent college grads from an ivy league school,  where 50% gave the answer above, which is wrong.  He uses it to show that many people we consider intelligent don't know the basic workings of our world.  That there is more to intelligence than a paycheck or a piece of paper from an institution.  This from a man who has a PHD.  But I agree.  Having lived 15 years in Phoenix, AZ.  I love the heat.

Comment: lololol I thought _that_ was the correct answer XD People mistake intelligence for accrual of knowledge/better memory.

Comment: The correct answer is that because to the tilt of the earth the light rays are more direct or concentrated.  Therefore warmer.  It is like turning your face towards the sun.  Intelligence is the ability to use useless knowledge to the betterment of society, both individually and as a whole.

Comment: But tilt means it's also closer?

Comment: not enough to make any difference.  When the sun is 93 million miles away the difference of the tilt in distance is not significant enough to be noticeable in the heat.  remember the earth is a ball.  Tilt a ball and it does not get closer it just rotates around the center of gravity which remains in the same spot.  we are actually closer to the sun in february.

Comment: Oh yeaaa duh XD Is there anything you don't know =P

Comment: @findwindow `What... is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?`

Comment: I heard of this joke before. Forget what the punchline is XD

Comment: @findwindow it is from Monte Python's Holy Grail.  `Bridgekeeper: What... is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?
King Arthur: What do you mean? An African or European swallow?
Bridgekeeper: Huh? I... I don't know that.`